# Find the general solution of $y''+p(t)y'+q(t)y = 1+t$

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

A solution of the equation $$y''+p(t)y'+q(t)y = 0$$ is $1+t^2$, and the Wronskian of any of two solutions of the equation is constant. Find the general solution of $$y''+p(t)y'+q(t)y = 1+t$$

I have been struggling with this question. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: you sure it's $1+t$?

Comment: I also find it strange but yes.

Answer (score 2):

$$y''+py'+qy=0$$
[Abel's identity](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbelsDifferentialEquationIdentity.html)  states:
$$W'+pW=0$$
Since the Wronskian is constant; $W'=0$ and $p=0$ since the Wronskian $W \ne 0$.

You can easily deduce $q(t)$
$$y''+qy=0$$
$$(t^2+1)''+q(t^2+1)=0 \implies q(t)=-\dfrac 2{t^2+1}$$
But the differential equation you are given is complicated to solve:
$$y''-\dfrac 2{t^2+1}y=t+1$$
You can reduce the order of the DE since you already know a solution and solve the homogeneous differential equation:
$$y''-\dfrac 2{t^2+1}y=0$$
You can use the Wronskian $ (W=C)$ also 
$$ W=\left|\pmatrix {t^2+1 & y_2 \\ 2t & y'_2} \right|=C$$
And find $y_2$ the second solution to the homogeneous DE.
$$(t^2+1)y'_2-2ty_2=C$$
It's a first order linerar DE.